# Files with Hyphen at Beginning of Name

Tags: linux, filenames

I have a bunch of files such as this `--4gqARaEJE_0.000.wav.gz`. How do I decompress them? Executing `tar -xz --4gqARaEJE_0.000.wav.gz` returns the error `tar: unrecognized option '--4gqARaEJE_0.000.wav.gz'`. Gzip returns the same error. I take it the hyphens are causing the error, but don't know the workaround.

I tried changing the file names to remove the hyphens, but that gives the same error. I also tried `\` prior to the file name, but no luck there either. How do you handle this kind of thing?

Comment: What happens when you try `tar -xz ./--4gqARaEJE_0.000.wav.gz`

Comment: You can always `mv ??4gqARaEJE_0.000.wav.gz 4gqARaEJE_0.000.wav.gz`

Comment: Just put the file name in doubt quotation marks: "--4gqARaEJE_0.000.wav.gz"

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman - That returns `Refusing to read archive contents from terminal (missing -f option?)`, but adding the `f` option doesn't work either. The ?? beforehand and double-quotes (" ") also did not work. Both of those still return unrecognized option error.

Comment: @TravisDickey can you try `tar -xz -- --4gqARaEJE_0.000.wav.gz`? that random `--` in the middle identifies that it's end of options.

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman the `--` seems to be on the right track. Haven't opened the file yet, but now I'm getting errors about the file not existing. So maybe it's corrupted. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @TravisDickey I've posted a reproducible complete answer below. Can you try it and confirm that it works? If it does, highly likely file is corrupted or extension is in reality different.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Must be a pretty narrow definition of development @jww. With a team of 5 people, I'm trying to create a pre-trained neural network that will classify the nature of audio clips. If that's not development, I don't know what is. Nevertheless, I get your point. In the future, I will pose similar such questions to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) first. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've tried a small example on my server.

With `wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/od1n/files/samples.tar.gz/download` I've downloaded a random sample file and saved it. File name was `download` initially.

I tried this:

```
root@server [~/stackoverflow]# mv download --download.tar.gz
mv: unrecognized option '--download.tar.gz'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

As expected, it didn't work but adding a `--` did help.

```
root@server [~/stackoverflow]# mv -- download --download.tar.gz
root@server [~/stackoverflow]# ls
./  ../  --download.tar.gz
```

Now our file name is `--download.tar.gz`, to extract it I used following command.

```
tar -xvzf -- --download.tar.gz
```

This still fails.

```
tar: unrecognized option '--download.tar.gz'
```

However specifiying folder location did work as intended.

```
root@server [~/stackoverflow]# tar -xvzf ./--download.tar.gz
samples/
samples/modifiedSheppLogan_256x256.smp
samples/fmri_64x64.smp
samples/qualityPhantom_64x64.smp
samples/brain_64x64.smp
samples/brain_64x64x5.smp
samples/qualityPhantom_64x64x5.smp
samples/modifiedSheppLogan_64x64.smp
samples/brain_256x256.smp
samples/qualityPhantom_256x256.smp
samples/brain_128x128x5.smp
samples/fmri_128x128.smp
samples/modifiedSheppLogan_128x128.smp
samples/qualityPhantom_128x128x5.smp
samples/brain_256x256x5.smp
samples/point_spread_function.smp
samples/qualityPhantom_256x256x5.smp
samples/brain_128x128.smp
samples/qualityPhantom_128x128.smp
samples/frequency_dist.smp
root@server [~/stackoverflow]# ls
./  ../  --download.tar.gz  samples/
```

In your case file might've been corrupted or the extension could be wrong.

Comment: Update: I was able to open the file using `gunzip -- --4gqARaEJE_0.000.wav.gz`. Thanks again for the help!